# How to store a Json data in one field?

Tags: php, mysql, json, implode

I know this question has been asked a lot and I have researched, trust me.

I have a Json file with multi variables in it. I want to take that Json file and store it in a single BLOB field on MySql Database.

I did json_decode() but when I try to store it, PHP gives me an error because json_decode() returns a php array but bindParam wants a string varaible.

I tried implode(",", json_decode($data,true)) but it didn't work.

Can you help me please...

My JSON file looks like this;

```
[
    { "xyz": "abc",
      "izd": 1
    },
    { "xyz": "abc",
      "izd": 1
    },
    { "xyz": "abc",
      "izd": 1
    }]
```

My PHP code is like this;

```
$json = $_POST["jsonfile"];
$jsondata = json_decode($json,true);
$implodedjsondata = implode(",",$jsondata); // In here, php gets error in impode ( Error : Notice: Array to string conversion)

$Query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(somedata) VALUES(:data)");

$Query->bindParam(':data',$implodedjsondata); // In case of not using implode, this line gets error( Error : Notice: Array to string conversion)
$Query->execute();
```

Thanks...

Comment: if i undestood well, you have to do json_encode, not decode.

Comment: @IsmaelFuentes Thank you so much, but this is not my fault , i overshadowed because of php.net manual translation :(

Answer (score 0):

its already a json? don't do anything with it, insert it as-is. and use bindValue, bindParam is an optimization thing when you have a lot of data you need to change fast when loop-executing a statement..

```
$json = $_POST["jsonfile"];

$Query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(somedata) VALUES(:data)");

$Query->bindValue(':data',$json); // In case of not using implode, this line gets error( Error : Notice: Array to string conversion)
$Query->execute();
```

Comment: Ok, I stored Json file but when I get this file on database, this returns an
Array not json. How do I fix this?